# Synchronous/Iterative tree recursion in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, express, promise

I'm having trouble trying to figure out a way to do recursion in such a way that it waits for one task/callback to finish and then execute the other after its done, for example I do this in my 'join' method:

```
exports.join = function(req, res){
  User.findById(req.user._id, function(err, user) {
     var dupe = []; //placeholder array
     var arr = user.forms_container.joinList;
     var title = user.forms_container.title;
     var myDate = Date();
     var newDoc = new Report();
     var tracker = 0;
     newDoc.author = req.user;
     var authorName = req.user.profile.firstName + " " + req.user.profile.lastName;
     console.log(authorName);
     newDoc.authors.set(0, authorName);
     newDoc.date = myDate;
     newDoc.owner = req.user;
     newDoc.title = title;
     //console.log(newDoc);
     newDoc.save();
     arr.forEach(function (rep) {
      console.log(rep);
                  Report.findById(rep).deepPopulate('subreport.subreport.subreport.subreport.subreport.subreport').execAsync()
                .then(function(doc) {
                    //console.log(doc);
                    dupe.push(doc);
                    treeCycle(doc, dupe);
                    console.log(dupe);

                    tracker = tracker + 1;

                    if (tracker == arr.length) {
                        //console.log(dupe); //returns [];
                        var counter = 0;
                        var masterbody ="";
                        for (var x = 0; x < dupe.length; x++) {
                            masterbody = masterbody + " " + dupe[x].body;
                            counter = counter + 1;
                        }
                        if (counter == dupe.length) {
                            newDoc.body = masterbody;
                            console.log(newDoc.body);
                            newDoc.save();
                            res.json(newDoc);
                        }
                    }

                }).catch(function(err) {
                    throw err;
                });
        });

    });
};
```

I used a promise for deepPopulate, but I don't know how to do it for my treeCycle function, which just iterates through each 'rep' (in the foreach) and does a deep populate on it and then a treecycle for my array dupe. What it is doing is though if I decide to run join on a array with [1, 2, 3] I want it to concatanate in that order as well, however if '1' has a subreport and '2' and '3' don't then '2' and '3' will finish their treecycle before 1. Then 'doc' holds the concatenation of '2','3','1'. So I just want treecycle to wait until the callback for '1' is done.

TreeCycle:

```
function treeCycle(doc, arr) {
  if(doc.subreport.length != 0) {
    for (var x = 0; x < doc.subreport.length; x++){
      arr.push(doc.subreport[x]);
      //console.log(arr);
      if(doc.subreport[x].subreport.length != 0) {
        treeCycle(doc.subreport[x], arr);
      }
    }
  }
  else {
    return arr;
  }
};
```

Comment: Why do you want to use a promise for this scenario?  It seems as though an iterative approach is what you want.

Comment: Yea, I just wanted to use promises for everything i guess, but they're pretty much asynchronous which is the opposite of what I want to do.

Comment: Ah - I've caught myself in that situation before :)

Comment: Well if `.deepPopulate` is asynchronous, then you cannot do it synchronously.